# Can I play 2-player with a main and sub account on the same PS4?

Tags: nba2k14

Once my sub account has been activated, can I play a two-player game with my brother on a single PS4 console?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Once you activate the 2nd controller it will ask for a profile to log in with. That profile will be your sub account. As long as both accounts are on the PS4 you can do it.